# How to get User's current location for every one hour?

Tags: jquery, cordova, sencha-touch

I am very new to phoneGap and am using the following code to watch the user's location.

```
var options = { enableHighAccuracy:true , frequency : 30000 };
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

But the problem is the success callback is triggering for every one second.I just want to take the User's position for every one hour.Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var controller=this;
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(controller.onLocationUpdate, controller.onLocationError, {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge: 3600000, timeout: 5000});
```

Here are samples of the two functions that the above will call based on an update or an error:

```
onLocationUpdate: function(geo) {
    console.log('location update');
    this.latitude = geo.coords.latitude, this.longitude = geo.coords.longitude, this.accuracy = geo.coords.accuracy, this.altitude = geo.coords.altitude, this.altitudeAccuracy = geo.coords.altitudeAccuracy, this.heading = geo.coords.heading, this.speed = geo.coords.speed;
},
onLocationError: function() {
    console.log('Location Error');
}
```